# Loop running infinitely

Tags: python

I have a while loop and it wont stop running the same loop over and over even when the condition is seemingly met. Probably just a dumb mistake but I can't figure it out for the life of me.

```
num = input("Enter a number:")

while isinstance(num, int) == False:
    num = input("Enter a number:")

while num > 1:
    print(num)
    if num % 2 == 0:
        num = num/2
    else:
        num = 3*num+1
```

it keeps running the first while loop even when the variable "num" becomes an integer. I tried to use an else statement to break the loop but it didn't quite work.

tried adding an else statement, tried using the type function instead of isinstance. no luck with any of them.

Comment: `input()` always returns a string. You have to call `int()` to convert it to an integer.

Comment: The function you want is `num.isnumeric()`. This tells you if a string looks like a number.

Answer (score 0):

`input` never returns an integer, so that condition will never be true.

`"1"` *looks* like an integer, but is a string. You'd need to explicitly parse it as a int using `int` first to get an integer. An easier check would be something like:

```
while not num.isdigit():
    num = input("Enter a number:")
```

But then you still need to parse `num` as an integer before you can do math with it later. This is also a common place to use `try` since attempting to parse the integer using `int` will reliably tell you if it's parseable, and if it succeeds, you have an integer.